# How to Execute DDL sql script depends on user input in Oracle DB

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

there is  two DDL script "s1.sql" and "s2.sql" , depends on user input any one of these script should be executed.

please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

To do a **conditional branching**, you could use a SQL*Plus variable to take user input. Using **DECODE** to identify which script needs to be executed based on the user's input.

For example, let's say you have two scripts `s1.sql` and `s2.sql`. You want to decide which script to execute  based on user input. If user inputs `s1` then execute `s1.sql` else execute `s2.sql`.

**Test case**

```
SQL> variable condition varchar2(20);
SQL> exec :condition := 's1';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> column which_script new_value this_script
SQL> SELECT DECODE(:condition, 's1', 'D:\s1.sql', 'D:\s2.sql') which_script
  2  FROM dual;

WHICH_SCR
---------
D:\s1.sql

SQL>
```

So, now you know which script to be executed.

Comment: Hi Executed the above script :

I am getting error.

variable condition varchar2(20);

exec :condition := 'Y';

@SELECT DECODE(:condition, 'Y', 'D:\1204\testing\test.sql', 'D:\1204\testing\test.sql') which_script FROM dual;

SP2-0310: unable to open file "SELECT.sql"

Comment: @  always expection file name

Comment: You don't have to put `@` in the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ACCEPT FILE_NAME PROMPT 'Enter S1 or S2 :'
@ FILE_NAME
```

It will ask you for the S1 or S2 and after input in the value it will execute the script through @ and don't worry about the .sql extension it will added by default.

Comment: @ FILE_NAME , FILE_NAME  value not replaced with s1 , its expection for FILE_NAME.sql file

Comment: and if you want to add some path in it then do the following, for eg.... @ C:\Scripts\&FILE_NAME